# How do I parse this html and use it as a variable in my ios app?

Tags: ios

Here is a sample of the html (the token #s change on the actual page):
http://nonlinearmind.no-ip.org:8888/token.html

From the page, I need to scape info for the following variables:

```
username = <title>
session = <h1>
token = <h2>
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have control over that `token.html` source? It would be best if it could return JSON or XML, rather than HTML. It greatly simplifies the parsing process.

But you could easily load the page into a `NSData` via:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nonlinearmind.no-ip.org:8888/token.html"];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"%s unable to load URL '%@'; error = %@", __FUNCTION__, url.absoluteString, error);
}
```

Or into a `NSString` via:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nonlinearmind.no-ip.org:8888/token.html"];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"%s unable to load URL '%@'; error = %@", __FUNCTION__, url.absoluteString, error);
}
```

You can parse it from there.

For example, to get all of the text between the `<h1>` open and close tags from the `NSString` called `htmlString`, you could:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<h1>(.*?)</h1>"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"%s regex error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
}

NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray array];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:htmlString
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [htmlString length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                         // the string including html tags is [htmlString substringWithRange:result.range]
                         NSRange matchRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];

                         [matches addObject:[htmlString substringWithRange:matchRange]];
                     }];

NSString *first = matches[0];
NSString *second = matches[1];
// etc.

NSLog(@"first=%@", first);
NSLog(@"second=%@", second);
```

---

I know you haven't said that you could do JSON, but if you could, the iOS implementation is incredibly easy. So, let's assume you had a URL that returned a JSON result like:

```
{
    "username" : "myusername",
    "session" : "mysessionidentifier",
    "token" : "somecryptictoken2340923923402309234"
}
```

You could then parse that with:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nonlinearmind.no-ip.org:8888/token.json"];
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                     options:0
                                       error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"%s data read error %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
    return;
}

NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                        options:0
                                                          error:&error];

if (error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"%s JSON parse error %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
    return;
}

NSLog(@"username = %@", results[@"username"]);
NSLog(@"session = %@", results[@"session"]);
NSLog(@"token = %@", results[@"token"]);
```

Comment: Oops... I noticed that.  My output is within <h1> tags - though I could make the output xml.  The code you gave me gets me much closer.  Thank you.  1 further question - how do I store the htmlStrings as individual variables?  Lets say I changed this to XML and had 3 tags - <username>, <session>, and <token>.  How do I output that to individual username, session, and token variables to pass along?  Sorry for so many questions - objective-C is very foreign to me!

Comment: @user1864132 I've updated my answer to extract the values from the HTML and populate an array with the matches, which you can then extract into variables as I demonstrate (I just called my variables `first`, `second`, but you'd obviously use more meaningful names).

Comment: I just looked into using JSON and feel like I'm not getting anywhere.  What I really need is to store my parsed <h1> as a value.  How do I store [htmlString substringWithRange:matchRange] as a string variable called "token"?

Comment: @user1864132 Ah, I see you figured out how to populate your JSON results at http://nonlinearmind.no-ip.org:8888/token.html. That's great, if you can make that work. It's a far more efficient way of communicating between systems. If you're struggling to figure out how to have your server generate JSON programmatically, it varies from server to server. But if your server has php, it would be http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php. If you're using another server scripting language, let me know what you're using and maybe I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I got it up and running, thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) for parsing HTML in an iOS app.

It gives you a detailed step by step overview of parsing a very basic HTML page, so it will be perfect for your example above.

It also shows you how to place your parsed Title into a TableView.
I think it more useful for you to understand the process of parsing, rather than just posting code to your question.